# How to not add tax before address in Woocommerce create new order menu?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I create a new order in the admin panel, the state tax is added immediately after I add the products. If I select a shipping address in a state where the tax is not configured, then the tax is reset as it should be, or remains if it is a state with a tax. I did not find how to remove this in the WooCommerce settings, but how can I remove it programmatically so that the tax is not added before the delivery address is selected?

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmgo6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1agS.png)

I can do something with Javascript on click but it's not a good solution

Comment: This is intended way. Ill recommend to leave it as it is. I dont see a problem if its updating based on the data you fill in.